# Identify the cubes in unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've create 2 cubes (cube 1, cube 2). When I click on either cube 1 or cube 2 I want to detects its name. How to do this in unity2d?

I already referred this link: [UnityGUI-click-event](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/120980/unitygui-click-event.html)

Comment: you can use raycast also if rays hit your object you can get info of hit

Answer (score 1):

Attach this script to your cubes:

```
public class ShowNameOnClick : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log(transform.name);
    }
}
```

You can read more about this events: [OnMouseDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) or [OnMouseUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html)

When I click on cubes now, their names are being displayed in console.

[image]

Comment: its ok  ... but in  unity3d we used tags to findout the names  ....                thank for ur help...                                                if(hit.gameObject.name=="3rd Person Controller")
{
Debug.Log("3rd Person Controller" );
}

Comment: you can get tag the same way `transform.tag`. I would say tags and object names are complementary.

Comment: :when i click on a cube or shere it should display the name on the gui box. how to do this.                                                       GUI.Box(new Rect(300, 100, 100, 20),""+collidedmesh)